# Typecasting PFObject subclass not working

Tags: parse-platform

In my Parse core, I have added a column that is a pointer to a `PFObject` subclass that I've declared as `PublicUser`.

[image: Parse]

In my app code, I tried to get a reference to this pointer and interact with it, by doing the following:

```
//IN Swift
let publicUser = PFUser.currentUser!.objectForKey("userPointer") as! PublicUser

//IN Objective-C (I think - I'm a Swift dev, providing this for reader convenience)
(PublicUser *) publicUser = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey: @"userPointer"]
```

However, when my app runs this line, the app crashes and I get the following error message:

`Could not cast value of type 'PFObject' (0x4e0210) to 'App.PublicUser' (0x95ba8).`

I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you call `Class.registerSubclass()` in your AppDelegate so your app can recognize your classes!

Answer (score 0):

My rep is to low to comment, but don't you need to query and fetch the object the pointer is pointing to before using it? I don't think objectForKey is fetching it.

Try to

```
println(PFUser.currentUser!.objectForKey("userPointer"))
```

Comment: Since the value you want is an object, you are correct - objectForKey does not fetch all the data. But that's for another problem, I found out I didn't call `registerSubclass()` and calling it in the appDelegate solved my problem.